# shopping cart with MS CRM Dynamics 4.0 integration?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics-crm

I'm looking for a product that will allow our members (we use crm as a membership database) to buy online media with CRM integration (get username/pass from crm, address, process cc, etc). Ideally it should end with writing back to the database that the product was bought and let us programmatically write a URL with the encoded info as a parameter to send to the media server: (http://example.com/access.asp?id=99343jfjf).

Also, if this isn't the way this is usually done with CRM please feel free to comment. I guess we could export the database periodically (every hour?) to a php/mysql based shopping cart, but I'm afraid of synchronization issues and duplicating data.  Supposedly, CRM supports a lot of functionality over its SOAP-based API.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have implemented and recommended [ADXStudio's](http://www.adxstudio.com/) products to our customers.